# How do I parse tr td from a string - such that it populates into 2 diff tables based on id

Tags: javascript, html, web

I get a return HTML like :

```
   '<tr id="x" ><td>Cool</td><tr>
    <tr id="x" ><td>Cool</td><tr>
    <tr id="x" ><td>Cool</td><tr>
    <tr id="y" ><td>Cool</td><tr>
    <tr id="y" ><td>Cool</td><tr>
    <tr id="y" ><td>Cool</td><tr>'
```

Now I need to parse this string and populate to 2 different tables . id=x goes to one table
id = y goes to another table .

My idea is to parse HTML tr td from a string and populate it to tables .

Comment: Can you use classnames instead? IDs must be unique. Do you use jQuery?

Comment: Note that your closing `tr` tags are missing a `/`, i.e. should be `</tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work :

```
$(yourstringvariable).find("tr").each(function(){
  var id = $(this).getAttribute("id");
  var name = $(this).find("td:first").html();
  // test id and add the name in the correspondig table here
});
```

But as the other said : id must be unique, so please use class instead. "$(yourstringvariable)" will create a DOM element corresponding to your string.

Comment: OP didn't say that jQuery is being used. But even if it is, your answer won't work.

Comment: Ah oops my bad, I'm so used to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery:

```
var input = '<tr class="x" ><td>Cool X1</td><tr>\n' +
    '<tr class="x" ><td>Cool X2</td><tr>\n' +
    '<tr class="x" ><td>Cool X3</td><tr>\n' +
    '<tr class="y" ><td>Cool Y1</td><tr>\n' +
    '<tr class="y" ><td>Cool Y2</td><tr>\n' +
    '<tr class="y" ><td>Cool Y3</td><tr>';


var data = $(input);

data.filter('tr.x').appendTo($('#x'));
data.filter('tr.y').appendTo($('#y'));
​
```

Here is the complete jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5muJd/